# Search Result with JQuery Click Event

Tags: php, jquery, dom

I am trying to create a search result template with a jquery click event...

```
if ( $result['template'] == "i1basic" )
    {
         echo "
            <script>$('#{$result['id']}').click(function(){ $('#{$result['id']}').hide(); });</script>
            <div id=\"{$result['id']}\" style=\"width:244px; height:244px; float:left; margin:2px; background-color:#{$result['color']}; background-image:url('system/content/images/{$result['image']}'); background-size:cover;\"></div>
        ";
    }
```

Comment: Put the script AFTER the element.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `on` since you create a div after you attach a `click` event to it, also just use `$(this)` to hide the element you're clicking on (just make sure you escape quotes correctly as I'm not a php guy so I used `\` to escape, not sure how it is in php)

```
$('body').on("click", \"#{$result['id']}\", function(){ $(this).hide(); });
```

or switch the lines with each other, i.e. put the `script` after the `div` as @Barmar suggested

here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/957ES/2/)

Comment: You need to use the delegation syntax of `on` for it to work with dynamically-added elements.

Comment: I have tried the code you suggest but am unable to see any change (http://www.squbo.com/temp4.php - search for physics - try clicking the element with the keywords)

Comment: @RobinStevens try my updated answer and let me know if it works

Comment: try using `$(this).hide();` as I suggested instead of `$('#{$result['id']}').hide();`

Comment: right now you have this `$(#random).hide();` which is invalid selector, so either use `this` as a selector or put quotes around `#random`

Comment: :) `this` should be without quotes

Comment: I have added the code I will require, not just hide which I was using to test with

Comment: <script>
       $('body').on(\"click\", '#{$result['id']}', function(){ 
        $('#squbo-website-header-search-form-term').val('{$result['id']}').keyup();
       });
      </script>

Comment: squbo.com/temp4.php - search physics - click the keywords square - it could be a dom issue

Comment: ok, try this `$('body').on("click", "#random", function(){ alert('test') });` if this doesn't work, then something is definitely wrong with your page

Comment: uploaded - this code is in a search.php file accessed by a search.js - would that effect it?

Comment: try to not create `<script>` dynamically and just put it in some JS file that you have referenced on the page... only instead of attaching `click` event to ID, attach it to class like this `$('body').on("click", ".random", function(){ $(this).hide(); });` and when you dynamically create div, add a `random` class to it `<div id=\"{$result['id']}\" class="random"....`. Let me know if it works, it might be that it doesn't like that you attach onclick dynamically

Comment: the idea is to not create `script` and onclick in particular dynamically and see what happens

Comment: although it shouldn't matter since you create dynamic content on the server and not on the client but still worth a try..

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach for dynamic html elements is actually

```
$(selector).on('click', function() { 
//your code here
});
```

However after taking a closer look at your code, i believe you should just add a class to the div, and externalize the css.

Say you add the class of .searchResult to the divs (granted they have their IDs), if you need their id on the click event just access it by the following code within the click function:

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated in newer versions

Comment: You are right, updating the answer now! Sorry 4AM :))